# mydata.lua link is not working in the cross-scene auido tutorial

Tags: audio, lua, coronasdk, scene

I'm Trying to do the lua (corona) tutorial for cross scene music play back from this site http://coronalabs.com/blog/2013/06/04/tutorial-handling-cross-scene-audio/#comment-465236 
The links "last week" do not work. Does anyone have myData.lua file or something similar. Thanks so much

Comment: This tutorial's links have been fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link missing in that article ("last week" / "Good bye globals") is this one:

http://coronalabs.com/blog/2013/05/28/tutorial-goodbye-globals/

It explains how to create a `mydata.lua` file.